# running criteria update query but getting the error Could not resolve binding for given parameter reference

Tags: jpa

i want to run the query for update,

update 
sensor_mediation_status
set(sensor_ip,DESKTOP-5KM9TE2),
set(last_item,890343480932434390)
where 
table=audio;

````
entityTransaction.begin();  

                CriteriaUpdate<SensorMediationStatus> update = criteria.createCriteriaUpdate(SensorMediationStatus.class);

                Root<SensorMediationStatus> from1 = update.from(SensorMediationStatus.class);

                ParameterExpression<String> table = criteria.parameter(String.class);
                update.set("last_item", lastItem.get(0));
                update.set("sensor_ip",lastip.get(0));

                        update.where(criteria.equal(from1.get("table"),table));
                entityManager.createQuery(update).setParameter(table, "audio").executeUpdate();
                    entityTransaction.commit();```
````

Comment: getting the issue to pass the column name in where clause

Answer (score 3):

Assigning the name to `ParameterExpression` should do the trick:

```
ParameterExpression<String> table = criteria.parameter(String.class, "tableParam");
```